# How to add project.pbxproj in.gitignore

Tags: react-native

> I got a merge conflict every time I try to pull or merge from gitlab.
> How to deal with these kinds of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't advise you to add project.pbxproj file to .gitignore. It is an important file in the Xcode configuration bundle. It is responsible for maintaining references to all of the linked files and their groupings, linked frameworks and the project’s build settings.

Take a look at [this](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/xcode-and-git-bridging-the-gap) article for further information.

However, if you want to ignore this file in the future,

1. commit all changes
2. `git rm --cached /App/App.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`
3. add /App/App.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj (or similar) to .gitignore
4. commit again

Answer (score 0):

project.pbxproj filein only first time upload in git and .gitignore file i'm provide to replace your  .gitignore file ...

```
# OSX
#
.DS_Store

# Xcode
#
build/
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
*.hmap
*.ipa
*.xcuserstate

# Android/IntelliJ
#
build/
.idea
.gradle
local.properties
*.iml

# node.js
#
*.hprof
node_modules/
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
yarn.lock
# BUCK
buck-out/
\.buckd/
*.keystore
!debug.keystore

# fastlane
#
# It is recommended to not store the screenshots in the git repo. Instead, use fastlane to re-generate the
# screenshots whenever they are needed.
# For more information about the recommended setup visit:
# https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/source-control/

*/fastlane/report.xml
*/fastlane/Preview.html
*/fastlane/screenshots

# Bundle artifact
*.jsbundle

# CocoaPods
/ios/Pods/
```